# Filtering by post date in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, filtering, drupal-views

For my current site I need to create archive for my news and articles that are older then 1 month. I tried to create new page in views, and use post date in filtering, but it just doesn't works as I intend. Instead of showing news I only need, it either shows all or nothing. Any ideas how can I make some kind of archive for my content?

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of the view you were creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issues was in incorrent input data. I tried to create filter for all content that is older then 30 days, but created filter for content that is younger then 30 days. Question solved

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [archive module](http://drupal.org/project/archive)?